# List of quosures as input of a set of functions

Tags: r, dplyr, future, rlang

This question refers to "Programming with dplyr"

I want to slice the ... argument of a function and use each element as an argument for a corresponding function.

```
foo <- function(...){
<some code>
}
```

should evaluate for example `foo(x, y, z)` in this form:

```
list(bar(~x), bar(~y), bar(~z))
```

so that `x, y, z` remain quoted till they get evaluated in `bar`.

I tried this:

```
foo <- function(...){
  arguments <- quos(...)
  out <- map(arguments, ~bar(UQ(.)))
  out
}
```

I have two intentions:

1. Learn better how tidyeval/rlang works and when to use it.
2. turn `future::futureOf()` into a function that get me more then one futures at once.

This approach might be overly complicated, because I don't fully understand the underlying concepts of tidyeval yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need any packages for this. `match.call` can be used.

```
foo <- function(..., envir = parent.frame()) {
   cl <- match.call()
   cl$envir <- NULL
   cl[[1L]] <- as.name("bar")
   lapply(seq_along(cl)[-1], function(i) eval(cl[c(1L, i)], envir))
}

# test    
bar <- function(...) match.call()
foo(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
bar(x = 1)

[[2]]
bar(y = 2)

[[3]]
bar(z = 3)
```

Another test

```
bar <- function(...) ..1^2
foo(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 9
```